# How do I check if a value is a number (even or odd) with type double in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I check if a value is a number (even or odd) with type double in  Dart?

Comment: How would you define even or odd for non-integer values?  First figure out his how you'd define that, or convert your `double` to an `int` first.

Answer (score 8):

```
  double value = 2.5;
  print(value.floor().isEven ? "It's even" : "It's odd");
```

Answer (score 4):

There are native methods for `int` to achieve that purposes. You can convert the number to an `int` and call `number.isOdd`, `number.isEven`...

Documentation:

```
abstract class int extends num {
   /// Returns true if and only if this integer is odd.
   bool get isOdd;
        
   // Returns true if and only if this integer is even.
   bool get isEven;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can go traditional with `String evenOrOdd = number %2 == 0?'even':'odd'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to detect from String.

```
 bool isDouble(String? s) {
  if (s == null) {
    return false;
  }
  if(int.tryParse(s)!=null){
    return false;
  }
  return double.tryParse(s)!= null;
}
```